# What are best practices for universal app vs. separate targets?

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal-binary

Are there any well established criteria to help decide between building a universal iphone/ipad app versus building separate targets that share some code?
 I have an iPad app working fine and now have a requirement to support iPhone. Since the iPad views are large and complex, I'll need to rework almost every one into 2 or 3 smaller iphone views.  So it seems to me that it will be easier to have 2 separate targets with all different views and controllers that re-use the model and communication layers, rather than pepper the code with:

```
    if iPad {
         // do iPad view and controller
    } else {
         // do iPhone view and controller
    }
```

TIA,

-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the users point of view universal is nicer, unless it makes the download substantially longer (artwork resources).

Comment: Oh yeah, the user.  I forgot about him :-)  Thanks.